# I'm trying to download all the files from a directory using Python's Paramiko module

Tags: python, upload, download, sftp, paramiko

I've got pretty much everything else worked out except this so any help here would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying to get this part to work for hours now and nothing I search for seems to be helping.

The problem is that  I can't seem to get the download function (get()) to work. My upload function (put()) works perfectly fine.. What this code does is creates a list of all the files that aren't yet on the server and then, using glob.glob to target all the files, it uploads the ones that aren't already there directly onto the server.

All I need to figure out, is how to download all the files from a directory onto my computer so that I can upload them to a different directory on the same server..if there is an easier way to do this please let me know.

```
import paramiko
import glob
import os
import fileinput
import shutil
from paramiko import sftp
from os import path

##This script uploads files from a local folder to a remote folder via
##SFTP and keeps track of which files have already been uploaded using "list.txt".

remotee = "//development//"
locall = "C:\\ftp\\Pangea"
complete = "C:\\moved"
mylist = "C:\\moved\\list.txt"
lastlist = []

class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password, host, port=22):
        self.transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
        self.transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
        self.sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(self.transport)

    def upload(self, local, remote):
        self.sftp.put(local, remote)

    def download(self, remote, local):
        self.sftp.get(remote, local)

    def close(self):
        if self.transport.is_active():
            self.sftp.close()
            self.transport.close()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        self.close()

with Server("username", "pass", "x.x.x.x") as server:
    for image in glob.glob("C:\\ftp\\Pangea\\*.*"):
        base = path.basename(image)
        server.upload(image, path.join(remotee, base))

for line in fileinput.input(locall + "\\list.txt"):
    lastlist.append(line.rstrip("\n"))

currentlist = os.listdir(locall)
newfiles = list(set(currentlist) - set(lastlist))

if len(newfiles) == 0:
    print("No files need to be uploaded")
    for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(locall):
        dst_dir = src_dir.replace(locall, complete)
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.mkdir(dst_dir)
    for file_ in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
        if os.path.exists(dst_file):
            os.remove(dst_file)
        shutil.move(src_file, dst_dir)
        shutil.copy(mylist, locall)
else:
  for needupload in newfiles:
      print("Uploading " + locall + "\\" + needupload)
      with Server("username", "pass", "x.x.x.x") as server:
          for image in glob.glob("C:\\ftp\\Pangea\\*.*"):
              base = path.basename(image)
              server.upload(image, path.join(remotee, base))
      with open(locall + "\\list.txt", "a") as myfile:
          myfile.write(needupload + "\n")
      with open(complete + "\\list.txt", "a") as myfile:
          myfile.write(needupload + "\n")
```

Comment: [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) is a bit higher level tool, which can download a remote file or files: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.get

Comment: Thanks but I'm using Python 3.3 on Windows and I'm pretty certain Paramiko has the tools needed to download the files.

Comment: The download function does a get... i assume your description needs a bit of an edit?

Comment: Just a curiosity... You have a double '//' in the remote path... ?

Comment: The double slashes are safeguards for the language itself in order to avoid special meanings such as /n for newline etc.